# Unable to click link/image due to hidden control C# coded UI test

Tags: c#, automation, coded-ui-tests

I am trying to click on an image that is also link. I keep getting the "can not perform click on hidden control (full error bellow). It's finding the image no problem through the Alt. Also found it with Src. Just can't get it to click. Any ideas? Thanks in advance

```
public void Checklinks()
{
    HtmlImage tourdates = new HtmlImage(newBrowser); 
    tourdates.SearchProperties.Add(HtmlImage.PropertyNames.Alt, "STS9.com home", PropertyExpressionOperator.EqualTo);
    Mouse.Click(tourdates);
```

Comment: Is your control hidden..?

Comment: It seems to be yes, is there a way to get around it? Thx in advance